# what are these codes which are used to edit configure files?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, emacs, edit, configure

almost every time I try to edit configure files of softwares I have to use some codes and commands which I have no idea about them. for example when I try edit `gvim` configure file I have to use specific codes or when I try to auto mount my partition in `fstab` I have to use another codes or when I was trying to edit `~/.emacs` I had to use some codes look like these(not the same)

```
(require 'cl)   
    (lexical-let ( (cols color-theme-choices) )
      (defun test-win-sys (frame)
        (let ( (color-theme-is-global nil) )
          (select-frame frame)
          (eval (append '(if (window-system frame)) 
                (mapcar (lambda (x) (cons x nil)) cols))))))
```

which I don't have any idea what do they called.
I really want to learn everything about emacs and ubuntu and be an expert.
My question has two parts:
1- Where do people learn these codes?
2- Are these a programming language? what do they called?

Comment: The eLisp code creates a function that captures the value of variable `color-theme-choices` - this variable doesn't exist in new versions of Emacs, could be part of an older themes package. The rest of the code is bizarre / possibly the person who wrote doesn't really understood what he / she were doing. But it basically returns the colours to use in a particular environment: when running under X-server or in console (I guess).

Comment: Oh, reading your other comment. The Emacs Lisp manual is here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html it is also accessible through Emacs / info interface, but advising you to try that would be evil, I guess :) Although it's recursive, so it may be an idiomatic thing to do :)

Answer (score 2):

You won't become "an expert" overnight.

1. There are *many* ways to configure programs in the UNIX world. What language, if any, is used will change from one program to the other so there is no single starting point for you.
2. In the UNIX world, *most* programs come with one or more "manual page(s)" that you can read with the `man` command. This is the canonical entry point when you have to use/configure a program you don't know and the first place you should look at when you are stuck.

   Type the command below to get the manual for `cron`:

   ```
   $ man cron
   ```

   How would you read the manual page for `vim`?

   Also, a (very) condensed version of the manual page is often available when you add the `--help` flag to the command:

   ```
   $ bash --help
   ```
3. "Simple" programs like `cat` don't really need much documentation beyond what's in `man cat` but more complex programs like `vim` or `emacs` come with an extensive inline documentation. Reading that documentation is probably necessary if you want to configure those programs correctly.

   The "splash screen" you get when you do `$ vim` or `$ emacs` tells you how to access the inline documentation.
4. Many programs also come with a "default" or "sample" configuration file; reading the manual will probably tell you if and where that file is and how to enable it.
5. You will probably see this acronym a lot, so allow me to be the first one to say RTFM.

Comment: I know about man page but problem is man page doesn't say about what is "require" command or what is "defun" and what do they do. after searching I found out that i have to learn about emacs lisp programming. I think 'man' can solve my problem in Unix based commands and not Lisp based like emacs codes.

Comment: @user175023, read my answer again, it is clearly laid out. Specially point 3: how to configure Emacs is explained in its documentation (`Emacs -> Customization -> Init File`) and how to access that documentation (`C-h i`) is explained on its splash screen. Same for Vim.